# Difference between using LIB and ar under cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, libtool, unix-ar

Under cygwin, with libtool I am trying to link a static library. the `--mode=link cl.exe` line invokes ar cru on the .obj files to create the .lib. However, I know there's another program under windows, LIB. As far as I understand, it's equivalent to ar, but will it make any difference in using ar+ranlib vs. LIB, and how can I force libtool to use LIB instead of ar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since setting `AR` and `AR_FLAGS` won't work, the only easy solution (that I haven't tried) is [CCCL](http://cccl.sourceforge.net/) which wraps up `cl.exe` and `link.exe` for a neater interface to those programs for autoconf packages.  It looks kind of old now, but it might work.

The installation instructions assume that `CC`/`CXX` are going to be `cl.exe`, but you're probably using GCC.  In that case, probably `AR=cccl` needs to be an argument to `configure`.